# JDeveloper 10g Form design view error

Tags: forms, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a strange problem in JDeveloper 10g.

Some forms I can't see in View window, and therefore I can't select and edit properties in Poperty inspector, also in UI complete structure is missing. 
[image: Forms without UI]

Besides that form is working OK.

This one is OK.

[image]

**How can I resolve this without the need for re-creation od forms?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved with this changes.
I don't know yet what caused this form to be erroneously created.

```
    //JScrollPane scPane = new JScrollPane(dataPanel); //This was surplus
    //topPanel.add(scPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);    //This was surplus
    topPanel.add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); //This was missing
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the JBinit method in place. Compare a working form to a non-working one.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in the right direction. Although JBinit was there something was surplus and something was missing.